# Plot a gene matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot, bioinformatics

I have a .csv file with gene counts and many samples (simplified below). I would like to be able to plots of total gene counts by sample. The file is in the format below:

```
       Sample
Gene    1        2
gene1   272.43    911.83
gene2   212.29    151.55
gene3   39.41      22.17
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking for, but perhaps this is what you have in mind:

```
library('ggplot2')
Sample <- melt(data.frame(Gene=c('gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3'), sample1=c(272.43,212.29,39.41), sample2=c(911.83,151.55,22.17)))
p <- ggplot(data=Sample, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_line(aes(colour=Gene, group=Gene))
p
```

Gives you this:

[image]